# Mongodb Query to Php Conversion

Tags: php, mongodb

Could someone please help me to convert this query for php?

```
db.job_crwaled.aggregate([{ 
"$geoNear": { 
"near": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [72.86,19.07]},
"spherical": true,
"maxDistance": 5000,
"distanceField": "distance",
"query": { "title": /sales/ }
}
}
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of R&D , i got the solution :

```
$c = $crawlingCollection->aggregate(
    [
    [ '$geoNear'=> [
        'near'=> [
            'type'=> 'Point',
            'coordinates'=> [
                72.86,
                 19.07
            ]
        ],
        'spherical'=> true,
        'maxDistance'=> 5000,
        'distanceField'=> 'distance',
        'query' => ['title'=> array('$regex' => 'sales')]
    ]]
]
);
```

php is blocking this /sales/ keyword thats why results were not coming so i used $regex keyword and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know does that work

```
$test = array(
  array('$geoNear' = array(
      'near' => array(
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' = array(72.86, 19.07)
      ),
      'spherical' => true,
      'maxDistance' => 5000,
      'distanceField' => 'distance',
      'query' => array('title' => '/sales/')
    ),
  ),
);
```

I am not sure what the `/sales/` was in your code. If that's just a `string` then it is good otherwise if it has some value save it on a variable and replace it with variable on the code.

Also please show us your code if you have tried some.

Comment: this code is working on mongodb console ..but not working with php